# address after const_cast of a *const* variable in C++

Tags: c++, const-cast

I know that the following should be undefined behavior
since the original variable is const. How is it possible, however,
that the two addresses `&x` and `&rx` are the same, yet the values
which they print (I don't say hold, since it simply cannot be),
aren't. Thanks!

```
const int x=10;
int& rx = const_cast<int&>(x);
rx++;
cout << x << " and " << rx << endl;
cout << "is &x == &xr: " << (&x==&rx) << endl;
```

the output from G++ 4.9 is

```
10 and 11
is &x == &xr: 1
```

Comment: You said it: it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Do you know what "undefined behavior" means?

Comment: the question is that the to objects point to the same chunk of memory and have the same type up to cv qualification, yet "hold" different objects...

Comment: Yes. It is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Check out http://goo.gl/ANHfS7 for a comparison between compilers and different optimization flags. While you should *never* rely on that kind of undefined behaviour, it sure is useful to understand what's going on.

Comment: @r0fg1 they don't hold different objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler (well, clang++ 3.7.0 as of last week) does indeed optimise the "intention" of the code, regardless of the legality of it:

```
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    movl    $10, %esi
    callq   _ZNSolsEi
    movq    %rax, %rbx
    movl    $.L.str, %esi
    movl    $5, %edx
    movq    %rbx, %rdi
    callq   _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l
    movl    $11, %esi
    movq    %rbx, %rdi
    callq   _ZNSolsEi
```

As always, it's worth noting that the behaviour of undefined behaviour does cover "does what you think it will do", as well as "doesn't do what you think it will do", and this CERTAINLY applies here.

`const_cast` of a value that was originally const is undefined behaviour, and at that point you have given up all rights to "sane behaviour" from the compiler. What happens now is whatever the compiler writer thinks is the right thing - and if that means the value actually got placed in a read-only bit of memory, then your code will not succeed in updating the value. But in this case, it simply optimises `x` to the constant 10, and `rx` becomes 11 - since you don't actually "do" anything else with `x` and `rx`, that's "fine" by the compilers standards.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly an undefined behaviour, therefore the question should, to my understanding, not be why it happens, but rather what makes it happen.

I'm don't know how GCC translates and optimizes code but my best guess would be that in the `cout` line, `x` is replaced by is supposedly const value at compile time (which the compiler assumes to be `10`).

It might be interesting to have a look at the assembly code produced !

Comment: sure! the funny thing was that `&x==&rx` but `*(&x)!=*(&rx)`, so that's would be one explanation, thanks!